# JDBC update with variable length IN clause

Tags: java, jdbc, kotlin, spring-jdbc

So I have a query I need to run like `UPDATE entity WHERE id IN (:ids)`. I know when doing a `SELECT` I can do something like

```
val sql = "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE id IN (:ids)";
jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, Collections.singletonMap("ids", ids));
```

Is there any way to accomplish this for an `UPDATE` query where I don't have to just turn my list of ids into a comma seperated string and call it like

```
val params = ids.joinToString(",")
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, mapOf(Pair("ids", params)))
```

EDIT: Turns out the second way I listed doesn't even work because it is expecting a Double and gets a string

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do this like this:

```
String joinedIds = Arrays.stream(tradeListIds).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Hey, thats useful to know. Thanks. Actually doesn't solve my problem though as it expects a double since the db entry is an `INT(11)`. I am using Kotlin and updated my example above (even though it doesn't work) to do it in a more kotlin-y way.